# PHP - how to pass my variable in my function

Tags: php

Someone can help me with that... How to pass a variable (`$membreConf`) in that:

```
$membreConf = '/home/mapubs/conf_maplate.php';
$route = new Route();
$route->add('/', function(){ include($membreConf); include('home.php'); });
```

Presently, is not working :(

Comment: What **exactly** is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the `use` statement is missing.
See example #3 of https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

```php
$membreConf = '/home/mapubs/conf_maplate.php';
$route = new Route();
$route->add('/', function() use ($membreConf) {
    include($membreConf);
    include('home.php');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You must pass it to the anonymous function using the `use` keyword:

```
$membreConf = '/home/mapubs/conf_maplate.php';
$route = new Route();
$route->add('/', function() use($membreConf) {
    include($membreConf);
    include('home.php');
});
```

See here the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), for example this code snippet:

> ```
> // Inherit $message
> $example = function () use ($message) {
>     var_dump($message);
> };
> $example();
> ```

You can also pass multiple variables:

```
function() use($var1, $var2, ...)
```